# Is coffee/caffeine addictive?

Tags: health, caffeine

I've heard that people get addicted. In other words, if someone has coffee regularly and they skip a day, then on that day they feel "low" or perform worse than they used to when they weren't a coffee drinker. Put another way, coffee no longer gives them a "boost"; rather, they need it to perform on par with when they weren't a coffee drinker. Is this true? What is your experience?

Any advice is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is, yes.

This topic has been discussed a few times and mostly related to caffeine. Please see this previous question:

- [Can decaf coffee be addictive?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/can-decaf-coffee-be-addictive)

And, about being low after quitting coffee after a while... This is mostly relevant to caffeine withdrawal and discussed on this question:

- [Why do I feel lousy, low, out of energy after the high coffee gives?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3228/why-do-i-feel-lousy-low-out-of-energy-after-the-high-coffee-gives/3229#3229)